# In LOTR with Sauron, what's the timing of Nazgul cards?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings

We were playing the LOTR board game (Reiner Knizia) with the Sauron expansion (me as Sauron).  On a player's turn, I played a Nazgul card.  They interrupted the card with yellow cards, putting the ring on, and Frodo's special power, and managed to end the scenario, and therefore avoided the entire Nazgul card's effects.

Is this right? I'd argue that although the interrupts seem reasonable, as the Nazgul card is based on a player's turn, and not the scenario, the affects should still happen.  What do others think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the players can interrupt the nazgul card and avoid its main effects.

First you must resolve the symbol in the upper left of the Nazgul card.  After that, because the main text of the Nazgul card treated as if an event tile were revealed, it can be interrupted by anything that can interrupt event tiles, such as putting on the Ring, Gandalf, etc.

If this ends the scenario, then the main text of the Nazgul card never occurs.